# Rebalance pooled disks

Tags: linux, hard-drive, diskmanagement

Using mhddfs multiple drives were pooled to form a big virtual mountpoint. Now using the mlimit option unbalancing is prevented, but the drives are already in an unbalanced state.

Is there a script or application to rebalance the disk usage?

If not, any convenient algorithms to implement?

Comment: admittedly not an answer, but why don't you use LVM2 and forget about "rebalancing" and stuff?

Comment: mhddfs has the property where if you lose a disk you only lose some of your data, not all of it, which is what would happen if an LVM volume was used and a drive failed.